# How do I pipe the last command in my command history to clipboard?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I'm a total noob when it comes to grep/awk/sed/cut so I need help with this. I've got this: `history | tail -n 1 | pbcopy` which returns `1968* mv ~/iPhoto\ Library.zip ./ ; bell` which is great because that's the last command I ran, but I need to remove the numbers at the beginning.  I've tried various iterations of `awk`, `grep`, `sed` and `cut`, but like I said I'm a noob when it comes to those kinds of commands. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pipe your output to

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s",$i OFS; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS}'
```

Output:

```
mv ~/iPhoto\ Library.zip ./ ; bell
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thanks. Stack Overflow's time limits won't let me accept this answer at the moment, but when I can, I most certainly will.

Comment: use single quotes `'`, because of shell expansion:

alias cmdtocb='history | tail -n 1 | awk '{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s",$i OFS; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS}' | pbcopy'

Comment: @polym what is `pbcopy`?

Comment: yea, that's not working either. I couldn't get the error output formatted correctly, so I deleted the original comment. It doesn't like the semicolon after the second printf in the awk command. I'm using zsh if that makes any difference here.

Comment: pbcopy is the command line interface to the OS X clipboard. It's really useful for things like copying file contents or command output. A simple example is would be creating a list of jpgs in a directory with `find ./ -iname '*.jpg' | pbcopy', or copying the source code of a website `curl example.com | pbcopy`

Comment: its not liking the `'` encapsulating the awk string. i corrected the alias here:

alias cmdtocb='history | tail -n 1 | awk \'{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s",$i OFS; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS}\' | pbcopy'

Does it work now?

Comment: alias cmdtocb='history | tail -n 1 | awk '"'"'{for(i=2;i<NF;i++)printf "%s",$i OFS; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS}'"'"' | pbcopy'

Edit: Ok it should work now, escaping single quotes in aliases are heavy.

Comment: strange... I'm still getting yelled at. parse error near ')' but I don't know which one. Thanks for all the help by the way.

Comment: oh... disregard the not working.. I hadn't seen your latest comment yet.

Comment: try escaping single quotes with `'"'"'`.. this ends the single quote string, escapes the single quote in double quotes and continues the single quote string again. phew, i learned something right there now, too :D

Comment: Works! brilliant! Thank you. Life in the command line just got 100x better.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this sed command,

```
history | tail -n 1 | pbcopy | sed 's/^[0-9]\+//g'
```

Through awk,

```
history | tail -n 1 | pbcopy | awk '{sub(/^[0-9]+/,"")}1'
```

Output:

```
mv ~/iPhoto\ Library.zip ./ ; bell
```

Comment: I think he edited the `*` to the history id for whatever reason.

Comment: @polym now it's ok. Why a long command this simple command will removes all the numbers at the starting `awk '{sub(/^[0-9]+/,"")}1'`

Answer (score 0):

In `zsh` you can just tell `history` (which is a synonym to `fc -l`) to not print the numbers with `-n`. Also, you can get it to print only the last entry with `-1`:

```
history -n -1 | pcopy
fc -l -n -1 | pcopy
```

In `bash` `history` has no options for this, but there is also a `fc` command, which even supports the needed options. Unfortunatelly, 'suppress command numbers' (from `man 1 bash`) seems to mean 'print a TAB instead', so the output starts with a TAB and a space, which can be removed with sed

```
fc -l -n -1 | sed 's/^\t //' | pcopy
```